# android image filtering for large images

Tags: android

I am creating an application which will take large images from SD card and then make them black and white and save them to SD card.I cannot read the large images directly.So need to use a stream.Can any one provide me with a solution.
PS:I tried a lot to find an answer for this issue,but has not been able to.
Thanking you in advance

Comment: Have you considered using the NDK? This sounds like a really easy task in C

Comment: Can't we use streams to read parts of the image file and then do the conversion in those bytes and then write back to the File?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `RandomAccessFile` to get access to the file in `read/write` mode:

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("yourimage", "rw");
```

than you can read a chunck of data with [public int read (byte[] buffer)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29), modify the data buffer in order to get the color of the pixel only black and whith, do a [public void seek (long offset)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek%28long%29) to return at the offset where you start reading and [public void write (byte[] buffer)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#write%28int%29) the black and with pixels.

EDIT:

Ok, actually I think that reading from file is not the solution since android does not allow to get the raw bytes of your image. You can use [BitmapRegionDecoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html), to read smull chunk of your image:

```
BitmapRegionDecoder decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(myStream, false);
Bitmap bitmapregion = decoder.decodeRegion(new Rect(left, top, right, bottom), null);
```

than use `ColorMatrix` to create a black and white image. If you can link aginst `libjpeg`, is straightforward get the raw bitmap bytes and convert it in black and white. The simplest way is the avarge method. You read 3 bytes a time (R, G, B). Then  takes the avarage:

```
unsigned char R;
unsigned char B;
unsigned char G;
int color = (R+G+B)/3; 
if (color > THRESHOLD) return 255;
return 0;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate,btw do you have any clue how to work on bytes to convert them into b/w or do similar processing??

Comment: Is there any work around for the function to work in 2.1 other than BackPorting the function?

Comment: no, without trying backporting it there is no way. IMO the NDK solution is better.

Comment: And How can I join them back after this conversion? I think the catch lies there.. We cannot join them back without loading the entire image into memory.

Comment: you can always read the image at small chunk. No need to load the entire bitmap in memory. Go with the NDK solution. Trust me

Comment: No I meant the BitMapRegionDecoder thing....I think that way we cannot proceed since ultimately we will want to rejoin the images,which will be impossible.

Comment: Go through the NDK solution. It is straightforwared and in the net you can read tons of libjpeg's tutorial

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13925/discussion-between-sreekanth-karumanaghat-and-blackbelt)